# Redirect to pd.ok365

Tags: html

I am owner of `hdasstios.ee.tn`, and I want to make when you enter `hdasstios.ee.tn` to redirect to `www.hdasstios.ee.tn/web/index.html`, so I wrote in root directory of website in index.html:

```
<html>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://www.hdasstios.ee.tn/web/index.html" />
</html>
```

,but I doesn't redirect to `.../web/index.html`, it redirects to [this website](http://pd.ok365.com/?dm=parked-domain.org&acc=455d5910-312c-4ad4-a979-956606aa2c4b&poprequest=1&ref=http://www.hdasstios.ee.tn/).

How can I fix this?

Please help me!

Comment: It looks like domain name issue. Are you sure you have registered the domain, and it still active? I would suggest contacting your domain regstrar.

Comment: I used freesubdomain.org.

Comment: And yea, website is active, try using www.hdasstios.ee.tn/fb

Comment: When I got to http://hdasstios.ee.tn I get redirected to http://www.hdasstios.ee.tn/site/.  Going to http://www.hdasstios.ee.tn/web/ redirects me to http://parked-domain.org/.  Are you sure you don't want to redirect to the "site" directory instead of "web"? Edit: You must have changed it.  Going to view-source:http://hdasstios.ee.tn/ shows you are redirecting to "site".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a non existing URL is accessed, by default the web server returns a [404 NOT FOUND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) response.

Your web server seems to be sending [302 FOUND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) (redirecting) to `http://parked-domain.org/` instead of [404 NOT FOUND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) response when a non existing URL is accessed.

Check web server configurations to fix this.

Comment: Yupp :) Thank you soo much!